# how to find the clientname of an remote desktop session?

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

We have servers on which we run tests and all users connect using the same credentials. The server allows 2 connections. What happens often is that one user is already active and the other two users keep hijacking the remaining session.

Using query session, I can find out what are the active connections. But it does not list the client machine from where the session originates, which taskmanager displays.

How do I get this information from a remote machine? I prefer a command line solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

netstat -n | find "3389"

also keep in mind that session may be disconnected and so have to disable disconnected session or set it on timeout

Comment: I am trying to find from a remote machine where the current sessions are connecting from. But if all else fails I can probably run this using psexec.

Comment: you also can make shared (r/o) folder and scheduled script like

>netstat -n | find "3389" > c:\Folder\Report.txt

and run this script every minute :)  so any who has access to c:\Folder\Report.txt can see active sessions :)

Comment: You definitely can run this using psexec, or use evg345's suggestion of a scheduled task.  Either way, this is a very workable solution and I think it's worth accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Well the simple answer is don't share credentials to cheat at terminal server licencing.

Comment: Thanks, EK. Unfortunately that is not an option. And let me assure you this has nothing to do with licensing :)

Comment: Sharing credentials does not defeat licensing restrictions.

Comment: Thanks John, I don't know whether it does. I was only mildly concerned  at EK's insinuation of illegal activity :)

Comment: no, I didn't mean that.  It was more of insinuating that it might be the wrong tool for the job. :)  People shy away from terminal server thinking that either it will be expensive or a big overhead